# Fundamental matrix for a given system of equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question is to find the fundamental matrix $F(t)$ satisfying $F(0)=I$ for the given system of equation below.

$$
x'
=\left(\begin{array}{rr}2 & 3 \\ -1 & -2\end{array}\right)x
$$

My solution is:

det($\begin{bmatrix} 
  (2-r) & 3\\
  -1 & -(2-r) 
\end{bmatrix}) = r^2 -1$

$r_1=1$ and $r_2=-1$.
Eigenvector of $r_1$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 
  -3\\
  1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and eigenvector of $r_2$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 
  -1\\
  1  
\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore
$x(t) = c_1\begin{bmatrix} 
  -3\\
  1  
\end{bmatrix}e^t$ + $c_2\begin{bmatrix} 
  -1\\
  1  
\end{bmatrix}e^{-t}$

I got stuck there, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, recall that a fundamental matrix is one whose columns correspond to linearly independent solutions to the differential equation. Then, in our case, we have
$$
\psi(t) = \pmatrix{-3e^t & -e^{-t} \\ e^t & e^{-t}}
$$
To find a fundamental matrix $F(t)$ such that $F(0) = I$, we simply taking the product
$$
F(t) = \psi(t)\psi^{-1}(0) = \pmatrix{-3e^t & -e^{-t} \\ e^t & e^{-t}}\pmatrix{-3 & -1 \\ 1 & 1}^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{3e^t-e^{-t} & 3e^t-3e^{-t} \\ -e^t+e^{-t} & -e^t+3e^{-t}}
$$
And we are ensured that $F(0) = \psi(0)\psi^{-1}(0) = I$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanations but I have a question. Why do you write $F(t) = \psi(t)\psi^{-1}(0)$ instead of $F(t) = \psi(t)\psi^{-1}(t)$?

Comment: Think about it: if we did that, then we would have $F(t) = \psi(t)\psi^{-1}(t) = I$, so $F(t)$ would be constant. That wouldn't make much sense...

Comment: So can we take any number istead of 0 or is it related with the condition the question gave us?

Comment: It is related to the condition. Say you picked $t = a$ instead. Then, $F(t) = \psi(t)\psi^{-1}(a)$ would be equal to $I$ when $t=a$.